# How to output a 4 byte string as a 4 byte integer in CPP

Tags: c++, converters

I am currently working on a Hash function and need to interpret a 4 byte string as a 4 byte integer number. Specifically I want every char value of the string interpreted as part of the integer number.

Comment: Didn't any of the answer answer your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can just copy the 4 bytes into a 32 bit unsigned integer variable to be able to interpret it as a 4 byte integer:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::uint32_t foo(const std::string& str) {
    if(str.size() != 4) throw std::runtime_error("wrong string length");

    std::uint32_t rv;
    std::memcpy(&rv, str.c_str(), 4);
    return rv;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << (1 + 256 + 65536 + 16777216) << '\n'; // 16843009
    std::cout << foo("\001\001\001\001") << '\n';      // 16843009

    // The result is platform dependent, so these are possible results:

    std::cout << foo("\004\003\002\001") << '\n';  // 16909060 or 67305985
    std::cout << foo("\001\002\003\004") << '\n';  // 16909060 or 67305985
}
```

Comment: This of course makes *huge* assumptions about endian forms, but otherwise, might work.

Comment: @tadman I assumed a hash that isn't required to return the same result on different platforms, like the normal `std::hash<>` hashes. If it's required to give the same result on different platforms, then OP:s own code won't work either

Comment: Likely the case, just adding as a caveat in case people start presuming.

Comment: @tadman Good, I found it important enough to make a note in the answer too. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

This function takes a string and interprets its char values as a 4 byte integer number.
Only tested strings with a maximum length of 4.

```
  uint32_t buffToInteger( std::string buffer ) 
            {
                uint32_t b = 0;
                for ( uint64_t i = 0; i < buffer.length(); i++ )
                {
                    b |= static_cast< unsigned char >(buffer.at( i ) << (24 - (4 - buffer.length() + i) * 8));
                }
                return b;
            }
```

Comment: It's better to check for the buffer length. If it is exceed 4, shift operator might cause a undefined behavior or possible arithmetic overflow.

Comment: I don't see how this is working. Is it working? `buffToInteger("\004\003\002\001")` gives the same result as `buffToInteger("\001\001\001\001")` which seems wrong.

Comment: I see, you've got the parentheses wrong and I think you can skip `4 - buffer.length()` since the result will always be `0` for a 4 byte string. Try: `b |= static_cast<unsigned char>(buffer[i]) << (24 - (i * 8));` and you'll get a correct result. You don't need to use the potentially throwing `at()` function since you will never get out of bounds (since you stay within `length()`.

Comment: You could just use a modern for loop? `for (char c : buffer) b = (b<<8) | (b>>24) | unit32_t(c)`

Comment: @MSalters Neat! Would `for (unsigned char c : buffer) b = (b<<8) | c;` be sufficient?

Comment: @ted: technically works, but will ignore all but the last 4 chars.